# how to broadcast messge when data connection is enable and disable in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    CheckinternetConnection internet;
    TextView textview;
    int tempint = 100;
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 5;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        internet = new CheckinternetConnection();

        schedueService();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(internet, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(internet);
    }

    class CheckinternetConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myserveclass.class));
                schedueService();
                //setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true);



            } else {
                textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textview.setText("It Seems Internet Connection is off");
                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myserveclass.class));
                CancelAlarm();

            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code  using this code i am able to display Connected and disconnected when application Launch i want as i  Enable data connection from Setting or Top of device then there should show Data is connected and as i will Off data connection then it should display data is not connected actully i want start service when My application has network connection and stop service when notwork is not connected suggest me how to implement this.

Comment: The connectivity manager already does this, you can follow this link for more info http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: i will have create Broadcast?

Comment: @iago i am using this code http://paste.ofcode.org/DmEXf32hLyXzGYZTbpV3x7   but the Error is coming  is null Pointer exception and Error is 42 number line

Comment: Is the code in another file? MainActivity.this will be null there

Comment: actully i want to implment this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html @iago there is Problem in undersatnd

Answer (score 0):

Try with this receiver
Also make sure you have the permissions in the Manifest

```
class CheckinternetConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager conn =  (ConnectivityManager)
              context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected==true)
            textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myserveclass.class));
            schedueService();
            //setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true);



        } else {
            textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textview.setText("It Seems Internet Connection is off");
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myserveclass.class));
            CancelAlarm();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one more thing i want to know if i have Network Problem and i have not disconnect data-connection then will it show Broadcast that disconnected coz application is not getting Network Connection